# Vertical transformation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, geoid

I recently bought a drone with a LiDAR sensor that collects and exports an .las file in GRS80, there are no options to collect in other geoids.  All of the jobs I work on or will work on are based on Geoid 12b.  How can I transform my .las file from GRS80 to Geoid 12b in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro will not do a vertical datum transformation on a LAS file, only vector data and raster data are supported.  Consider using vDatum.  vDatum is a free and open source software package that will do vertical datum transformations on LAS files.  S[ee here for more information](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html).